# Grafana create query variable from table

Tags: grafana

So I am new to Grafana, I have a table and a bar chart:

[image]

The bar chart query is as follows:

```
select coalesce(group_name) as group_name,
  sum(sales) filter (where device_type = 'HEAD_PHONES') as HEAD_PHONES,
  sum(sales) filter (where device_type = 'GUITAR') as guitar,
  sum(sales) filter (where device_type = 'XBOX') as xbox,
  sum(sales) filter (where device_type is null ) as other
from test
where area = 'AREA1' <--make this grafana variable
group by coalesce(group_name);
```

I would like if every time the user clicks a row within the table, the bar chart is updated using the same query but the area changed depending on the row clicked. How do I make it a Grafana variable supposing there are more than a 100 areas?

Here is db:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In grafana there is "variables", go to "dashboard settings" --> variables, from there create new variable with type "query", name it like "area" and put sql query(select area from test), save it, and then in your select query:
select ... where area in ($area).

reference https://docs.timescale.com/timescaledb/latest/tutorials/grafana/grafana-variables/#using-grafana-variables

Comment: Okay, how do I make the row clickable within Grafana so that it updates within the bar_graph?

Comment: I was able to use a URL link and pass the cell value into the URL to achieve what I wanted. Thanks @Jonibek for pointing me in the right direction. I used this as a resouce: https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/linking/data-link-variables/